Powerapps comparison of datetime column and today()
I'm new to PowerApps. We have a table to store user holiday balance between 2 dates.

Column 1: fromdate, datetime column
Column 2: todate, datetime column
Column 3: balance, decimal column

I have a label on a canvas,  and would like to display the balance based on today's date being between the from and to dates.
LookUp(UserBalances, Today() >= fromdate && Today() < ToDate && User = User().Email).balance& "hrs"

However, we get the following error:

Error when trying to retrieve data from the network: The left side of the 'Equal' operator must be a property of the entity.


shouldnt it be enough to switch Today() >= fromdate to fromdate <= Today() as this is basically what the error says? Do this for every comparison and see if it works

@Aaron WOW!!  i just neve clicked!   thats fixed it..
